# Kinect with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, kinect

I will draw a 3d model on the screen with OpenGL and I will zoom or rotate this model on the screen with Kinect gestures.Does anyone have a good tutorial or information how can i start programing C++/OpenGL application using Kinect.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're talking about two fairly broad topics here, so you'll need to narrow down your question before we can provide a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're faceing very different problems here:

1. You need to master OpenGL so that you can draw anything useful. I recommend a combination of reading "The OpenGL Programming Guide" (aka Red Book), the "OpenGL Super Bible" and the tutorials at http://www.lighthouse3d.com and http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut .
2. You need to get familiar with computer vision and gesture recoginition. The Kinect is just a depth camera, i.e. for each pixel in the image you're getting the distance from the camera. In addition to the depth sensor, there's also a regular camera, so you can combine depth and color information. But the Kinect does not give you gesture data directly. You need it to hook to some computer vision system that determines the gestures from the data Kinect delivers.

And then you need to merge those into a useful program.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [Zigfu dev bundle](http://www.zigfu.com) for windows/mac kinect development. It is the easiest way to install OpenNI/NITE and Kinect drivers.

OpenNI comes with a bunch of full source samples, including [NiSimpleViewer](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Samples/NiSimpleViewer/NiSimpleViewer.cpp) - which renders the kinect depth data using OpenGL.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search yields this : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/new.aspx

I suggest you start by downloading the Kinect SDK. I'm sure there's a few examples to get you started. And luckily for you the SDK seems to support c/c++ (with MS Visual Studio 2010), so it appears you're not confined to C# or xna.

Comment: Thank you. But unluckily, there is not enough information about how to implement in C++ with KinectSDK.