# How to start learning the basics to write program in C++ for XBOX 360 KINECT for developing windows application?

Tags: c++, image-processing, kinect

I have a basic knowledge of c++. And i want to learn how to write program for Kinect Sensor.
I have seen many websites with examples of programs for Kinect Sensor in c++, but none of them have explained it well enough to understand whats happening in the code they have written.

so tell me how can start learning the basics to write programs for Kinect Sensor.

if there are any tutorials (preferably video tutorial), so tell me about them also.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: Please bear in mind that the Kinect for Xbox 360 can not be used in production when relying on the Kinect for Windows SDK for development. The users of your software will have to buy a Kinect for Windows sensor. Also, the Kinect for Xbox360 does not support near mode, a special firmware feature which shifts the effectively usable range of the depth sensor towards the device. This feature is desirable for desktop applications, where the user is very close to the sensor.

Comment: @ChrisOrtner yes i know that. but thank for telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinect   C++ here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/394975/How-To-Use-Kinect-Face-Tracking-SDK

and here : http://nsmoly.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/face-tracking-sdk-in-kinect-for-windows-1-5/

Answer (score 0):

There are videos and documentation at the [Kinect Learn site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/learn.aspx). You should probably start from there.

Comment: they only have video tutorials on how to write programs in C# and VB... and not for c++... so do you know any c++ related tutorials to program for Kinect Sensor.. but i appreciate your quick response..

Answer (score 0):

A quick google brings up this page which is a C++ Kinect tutorial. It's in Russian, but Google Translate could help you with that: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123588/

Also this similar (but poor quality so now closed) question may be of use: [Kinect with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9191471/769220)